# I want to limit the selection of check box. Only one should be checked

Tags: php

I want to limit the check "1"

```
<li>
  <div class="label_box">
    <label>{translate text="view"}</label>{$action_object->check_required('view_type')}
  </div>
  <div class="input_box">
    <ul class="cb_options_list_short" id="cb_view_type">
      {foreach item=conf key=value from=$action_object->m_form_fields.view_type.options}
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="view_type_{$value}" id="view_type_{$value}" value="{$value}" {if $conf.value==$value}checked="checked" {/if} /> <strong>{$conf.label}</strong></li>
      {foreachelse} {if $action_object->m_is_admin}
      <li><a href="{site_url uri='admin/view_types'}">{translate text='view_types_view'}</a></li>
      {else}
      <li><strong>{translate text='n.a'}</strong>
      </li>
      {/if} {/foreach}
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you tag the template engine you are using?

Comment: If you only need one use radio.

Comment: i tried to use radio could not manage. i am not a pro. so if you can help me with the link will be good. thanks